# Take specific number from output

Tags: sed, grep

This is the output of some `svn log` command of me

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r23327 | xxx | 201x-0x-1x 15:09:20 +0200 (Mon, x x x) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /line/tags/1.1.1.1 (from /line/branches/uat:23326)
```

I want to grep or sed the nummber `23327` out of the output. Someone who can help me? I want it to work too with other numbers but same layout.

I tried something like

```
txt | grep '^r'
r23327 | xxx | 2017-05-15 15:09:20 +0200 (Mon, 15 May 2017) | 1 line
```

But I need to get rid of the 'r' and stop before the space before |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***sed*** approach:

```
sed -n 's/^r\([[:digit:]]*\) .*/\1/gp' file
```

The output:

```
23327
```

`\([[:digit:]]*\)` - captured group for digits preceded by `r`

---

Or with ***grep*** (PCRE):

```
grep -Po '^r\K[0-9]+ ' file
```

`-P` - allows PCRE

`\K` - ignores matches till the current position (i.e. ignore `r` before digits)